# Android save image as Favourite

Tags: android

I have app which has around 100 images which are stored in drawable folder.Now I want to put a favourite button in that image.If user clciked that button that particular image is saved to Favourite Activity.I am using viewpager for showing images.
Please tell me how can I do it?

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: I have 100 images in my app.I have main activity and favourtie activity.I am using view pager for showing images.Now If user like any images from that user can click on button which is on bottom bar.When he click that button images is saved in favourite activity.And user can show that images.If he did 10 images as favourite then in favourite activity user is able to see that 10 images.

Comment: `that particular image is saved to Favourite Activity`. You cannot save images in activities. An activity is no storage place. One can display images in an activity yes. So now tell us how the activity knows which images it has to display. And should it display the same after restart?

Answer (score 0):

Store that particular id in arrayList and use that arrayList in your FAV activity.

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter do as following

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    final View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.boost, container, false);

    final AdapterList list = adapterList.get(position);

    final ImageView image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
    image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image_name));

    final Button favorite = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.favorite_button);

        activateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            if (!isFavorite) {
                    saveAsFavorite(list.getPackageId());
                    isFavorite= true;
                }else{
                    notFavorite(list.getPackageId());
                    isFavorite= false;
                }
            }
        });

    container.addView(itemView);

    return itemView;
}
```